# Visual Studio Code Intellisense Not Working in React project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have my VS code intellisense stop working suddenly in my react project. After restarted VS code, it works again, but only in a short amount of time. Whenever I hit enter, the intellisense won't work anymore. Tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>  but only loading pop up I'd got and even I got no error/lint not works. Strangely it works in the other (not react) project properly.

I have tried reset setting, restart ts server, add jsconfig, install @types/node, disable every extension, uninstall all the extensions, re-install VS code, but nothing works.

Comment: When you re-installed vscode did you completely remove it as the following https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/visual-studio-code/remove-vs-code-completely.html. I had a similar problem when upgrading from VSCode 1.39 to 1.41 and after cleaning everything out it worked again.

Comment: I've just tried the link you gave but still not works. I am start feeling frustrated now.